# an swf file can't read data from config.xml file in the same Flex directory

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I have a main swf file and config.xml located in the same directory. My .swf file uses config.xml to fetch config variable which it does with success.

The problem appears when I put those files into Flex directory. I embed .swf file like this.

```
<mx:Image id="loading" source="@Embed('/blobs/visualLogo/mySwfFile.swf')" 
visible="true"  horizontalCenter="0"/>
```

I also place config.xml into /blobs/visualLogo/

This time I get an error in Flex:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at mySwfFile_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

What's wrong with it?

Comment: can you paste your xml file path

Comment: @chrisiek can you provide code that load xml in `mySwfFile.swf`

Comment: but it is hardcoded in swf...textLoader.load(resUrl)
function resLoader(cb) {
 resUrl = new URLRequest()
 textLoader = new URLLoader();
 textLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, textLoaderComplete);
}

Comment: Because the code is not mine I had to investigate a little. The code loading config.xml is located in the first frame:
 
import minetext.steel

stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
stage.align = "TL";

addChild(new steel("config.xml"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `@Embed` here, the "current directory" of the embedded SWF will be determined by the *embedding* SWF. It's looking for `config.xml` in the same directory as the main SWF, and that's why it's failing.

Try using the full path to `config.xml` in the child SWF, or just move `config.xml` into the same directory as the main SWF.

Comment: Notice, as I described earlier, that I put the both files .swf and config.xml in the same directory in Flex directory tree. Suprisingly it doeasn't work.

Comment: You are right. Files should be in the same directory. I added @Embed into event handling function that handles creationComplete event for the application. For some reasons my swf file couldn't read config.xml too early before full initialisation of the application.